# Why EMF is induced in the following situation?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current

Why emf is induced in the conducting wire even though there is no flux change or motion(for motional emf) in the following situation?

A conducting loop in the shape of right-angled isosceles triangle of height 10cm is kept such that the 90° vertex is very close to an infinitely long conducting wire (see the figure). The wire is electrically insulated from the loop. The hypotenuse of the triangle is parallel to the wire. The current in the triangular loop is in counterclockwise direction and increased at constant rate.[image]

Now since the wire is not moving no motional emf can be used but according the answer a current in induced in left to right direction, why is it so?

Comment: Why do you think they have mentioned that there is a increasing current in the triange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

So here my previous interpretation of the question wrong. We take the value of current in the Infinite Wire to be 'i'. Now the flux through the triangle loop at any point would be $$\Phi = \int \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dA} = \int_{0}^{0.1} \frac{\mu_0 i}{2 \pi x} \times 2x \times dx = \frac{\mu_0 i}{2\pi}$$. Now we can say that $\Phi = Mi$ so $M = \frac{\mu_0}{2\pi}$ and emf $\epsilon = M\frac{di}{dt}$ here you can input the rate of change of current and get the emf.

This is mutual induction and $M$ is the coefficient of mutual induction [source](https://infinitylearn.com/questions/physics/conducting-loop-shape-right-angled-isosceles-triangle-height)

Comment: But the infinite wire does not initially have any current and hence no magnetic field. So how can they be coupled?

Comment: @GarvChaudha I apologize my previous interpretation of the question was incorrect. I have edited and included the source of the solution

Comment: Thank you. I understood how the EMF is calculated. But I still can't understand why the EMF is induced in wire since changing the current in the triangle doesn't change the flux through the wire. How do we define the flux through the wire because of the magnetic field produced by the triangle since there is no loop formed by the wire?

Comment: @GarvChaudha The law states that the flux through a wire should be reduced or oppose the increase of flux. So when the field from the wire and the loop both are passing through the loop, the loop will try to reduce the flux because of which the current in the wire will be induced towards the left direction